# Circumstances under which die() does not exit a Perl script?

Tags: perl

I'm debugging a really weird problem with a long-running Perl script.

The problem is that the script does not exit on `die()` as expected. Instead the script just hangs without returning.

I've not defined any error handlers myself so I would assume that `die()` would lead to an immediate termination of the script.

This is the basic structure of the script and the modules used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use DBI; # with MySQL driver ("dbi:mysql:database=...")
use Geo::IP;
use POSIX;
use URI::Escape;

open(COMMAND, 'command_line |');
while (<COMMAND>) {
    #
    # .. stuff that can go wrong ..
    #
    die("I'm expecting the script to terminate here. It doesn't.") if ($gone_wrong);
}
close(COMMAND);
```

What could be the explanation to this behaviour? Is any of the modules used known to set up error handlers that could explain the script hanging on `die()`?

Comment: Add a debug line right before your `die()` call: `warn "DIE = $SIG{__DIE__}"` to see if there is a die handler present at that time.

Comment: What is the 'command_line' program? And are you using the mysql DBI connection inside the loop?

Comment: are you seeing the `die` message? your question doesn't make that clear. if not, adding the `warn` right before it would show whether you are actually reaching the `die`. apologies if this seems obvious!

Comment: Core: The command_line program is a normal Linux application that writes to STDOUT. Nothing fancy and nothing that should interact with the Perl script more than via what's written via the pipe. The mysql DBI connection is used inside the loop, yes.

Comment: Are you sure the $gone_wrong condition is being met? Like others have said, add a warn/print statement in there to see. Those should happen independently of any __DIE__ handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `END` blocks and object destructors are still called after a `die`.  If one of those hangs (or does something that takes a long time), the script won't exit immediately.  But that should happen *after* printing the message from `die` (unless STDERR is buffered so you don't see the message immediately).

You mention DBI, so you probably have a database handle whose destructor is being called.  (I'm not sure that's the problem, though.)